# Securing account login info while trying to retrieve data from an api using JS

Tags: javascript, api

I'm very new to JS and I've been trying to add some automated elements to my website using JS (and Jquery).

After about 6 hours probing the mediafire api I have managed to access the data (download count) I want to show on the website.

After a few more hours googling about security of the data inside the JS file it seems anyone could just read the code and take the login info.

So my question is:

How can I secure my login credentials and then somehow access this data to run through my script and pull the data?

I understand that I would not want to just send the username and password from this code/or call and I would instead just supply the JS script the end api call for it to run.

My knowledge of any other languages apart from HTML CSS and JS are 0.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a good way to do this in your JavaScript.  You can obscure your credentials by encoding them or using MD5, but at some point you'll need to decode them to supply them to the external API.  Since that decoding event would be happening on the client-side, the client would have access to your credentials in the clear at that point.

To add any meaningful level of security, you'll need to store credentials server-side and keep them out of your client-side code altogether.  There are many methodologies to accomplish this, depending on your backend.  How is your site hosted?  Can you run code on your backend server?  If so, you should explore consuming the API from your backend and passing along just the data to your client-facing code.

Comment: Its a wordpress hosted website.